# how to join unnested parquet files having different structure to form a single parquet table

Tags: xml, join, aws-glue, parquet, flatten

I have an xml file with following schema -

```
root
|-- _schemaVersion: double
|-- _xmlns: string
|-- ecuList: struct
|    |-- ecu: array
|    |    |-- element: struct
|    |    |    |-- dtcs: struct
|    |    |    |    |-- dtc: array
|    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- description: struct
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _textId: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- envDatas: struct
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- envData: array
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: struct
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _textId: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- unit: struct
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _textId: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: struct
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _textId: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- number: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- statusesOfDtc: struct
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- statusOfDtc: array
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: struct
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _textId: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- unit: struct
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: null
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _textId: null
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: struct
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _textId: string
|    |    |    |-- name: struct
|    |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string
|    |    |    |    |-- _textId: string
|    |    |    |-- parameters: struct
|    |    |    |    |-- group: array
|    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- groupName: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- parameter: array
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- default-value: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: struct
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _textId: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- original-value: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- unit: struct
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _textId: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: struct
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _textId: string
|-- generalData: struct
|    |-- ProtocolType: string
|    |-- collectionDate: string
|    |-- deisLanguage: string
|    |-- deisVersion: string
|    |-- model: string
|    |-- vin: string
```

I used relationalize transform in aws glue and wrote the flattened files in parquet format to s3 bucket using aws glue job.
Following is the table structure of the multiple parquet files generated from the xml file above -
df1 = root

```
root
|-- _schemaVersion: double
|-- _xmlns: string
|-- ecuList.ecu: long
|-- generalData.ProtocolType: string
|-- generalData.collectionDate: string
|-- generalData.deisLanguage: string
|-- generalData.deisVersion: string
|-- generalData.model: string
|-- generalData.vin: string
```

df2 = "root_eculist_ecu_parameters_group"

```
root
|-- id: long
|-- index: int
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.parameters.group.val.groupName: string
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.parameters.group.val.parameter: long
```

df3 = "root_eculist_ecu"

```
root
|-- id: long
|-- index: int
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.name._VALUE: string
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.name._textId: string
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.parameters.group: long
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.dtcs.dtc: long
```

df4 = "root_eculist_ecu_dtcs_dtc_statusesofdtc_statusofdtc"

```
root
|-- id: long
|-- index: int
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.dtcs.dtc.val.statusesOfDtc.statusOfDtc.val.name._VALUE: string
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.dtcs.dtc.val.statusesOfDtc.statusOfDtc.val.name._textId: string
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.dtcs.dtc.val.statusesOfDtc.statusOfDtc.val.value._VALUE: string
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.dtcs.dtc.val.statusesOfDtc.statusOfDtc.val.value._textId: string
```

df5 = "root_eculist_ecu_dtcs_dtc_envdatas_envdata"

```
root
|-- id: long
|-- index: int
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.dtcs.dtc.val.envDatas.envData.val.name._VALUE: string
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.dtcs.dtc.val.envDatas.envData.val.name._textId: string
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.dtcs.dtc.val.envDatas.envData.val.unit._VALUE: string
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.dtcs.dtc.val.envDatas.envData.val.unit._textId: string
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.dtcs.dtc.val.envDatas.envData.val.value._VALUE: string
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.dtcs.dtc.val.envDatas.envData.val.value._textId: string
```

df6 = "root_eculist_ecu_dtcs_dtc"

```
root
|-- id: long
|-- index: int
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.dtcs.dtc.val.description._VALUE: string
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.dtcs.dtc.val.description._textId: string
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.dtcs.dtc.val.envDatas.envData: long
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.dtcs.dtc.val.number: string
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.dtcs.dtc.val.statusesOfDtc.statusOfDtc: long
```

df7 = "root_eculist_ecu_parameters_group_parameter"

```
root
|-- id: long
|-- index: int
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.parameters.group.val.parameter.val.default-value: string
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.parameters.group.val.parameter.val.name._VALUE: string
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.parameters.group.val.parameter.val.name._textId: string
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.parameters.group.val.parameter.val.original-value: string
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.parameters.group.val.parameter.val.unit._textId: string
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.parameters.group.val.parameter.val.unit._VALUE: string
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.parameters.group.val.parameter.val.value._VALUE: string
|-- ecuList.ecu.val.parameters.group.val.parameter.val.value._textId: string
```

I want to join all the parquet tables to form a single parquet table. How to join these tables? On which keys to join? Please help. I didn't come across any examples on internet and I would really appreciate your help. Thank you